# Jquery Mobile and Graphael not working together

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, raphael, graphael

I am trying to draw a pie chart using jquery mobile and graphael and having no luck with it. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Anyone has any pointers? Here is the javascript i used from http://www.artetics.com/Articles/using-various-javascript-libraries-to-create-pie-chart

```
     //Push our data into two separate arrays
  var labels = [];
  var values = [];
       for (i in data.items) {
         var item = data.items[i];
         labels.push(item.label);
         values.push(item.data);
       }
  //Lines below will draw the chart
  window.onload = function () {     //We will draw in our div
    var r = Raphael("graphaelExample");
    //Text settings
    r.g.txtattr.font = "12px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif";
    r.g.text(320, 100, "Number of posts").attr({"font-size": 20});

    //Create pie
    var pie = r.g.piechart(320, 240, 100, values, {legend: labels, legendpos: "west"});
      //We will adjust UI when mouse over the chart sector
    pie.hover(function () {
      this.sector.stop();
      this.sector.scale(1.1, 1.1, this.cx, this.cy);
      if (this.label) {
        this.label[0].stop();
        this.label[0].scale(1.5);
        this.label[1].attr({"font-weight": 800});
      }
    }, function () {
      this.sector.animate({scale: [1, 1, this.cx, this.cy]}, 500, "bounce");
      if (this.label) {
        this.label[0].animate({scale: 1}, 500, "bounce");
        this.label[1].attr({"font-weight": 400});
      }
    });
  };
```

and here is the html. I did include the raphael libs as resources on the jsfiddle.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
        <head> 
        <title>Page Title</title> 

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body> 

    <div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">    
            <div id="graphaelExample"></div>        
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't see a link to a JSFiddle anywhere. Do you have one?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Gkhae/

The above works, i think the javascript snippet was wrong. Copied the one from g.raphael examples and it seems to be working.

Comment: Could it be the window.onload function?